# OpenGL texture stretched and wrong. VBO vertices incorrect?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I've been trying to solve the problem of my cube texture vertices being incorrect for well over a day now without much luck. The texture is showing up wrong, and it's different on every sside.

Here is my code at the moment. I think it's relatively straightforward for someone familiar with OpenGL, but if you have any questions ask.

Last time I posted this a few days ago I was downvoted and got no answer; If I'm not giving you enough info or doing something wrong, let me know.

```
   private boolean hasBeenRendered = false;
   private int amountOfVertices;
   private int vertexSize;
   private int textureSize;
   private int vboVertexHandle;
   private int vboTextureHandle;
   private boolean canDraw = false;

   public Block(BlockType type, Location loc) {
      this.type = type;
      this.loc = loc;

      initRendering();
   }

   private void initRendering() {

      amountOfVertices = 24;
      vertexSize = 3;
      textureSize = 2;

      FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * vertexSize);
      float[] vertices = {
          //  X     Y     Z           R     G     B
          // face 0:
          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       // vertex 0
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,        // vertex 1
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,        // vertex 3
          1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,        // vertex 2

          // face 1:
          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       // vertex 0
          1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,       // vertex 1
          1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,       // vertex 3
          1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,        // vertex 2

          // face 2:
          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      // vertex 0
          1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,       // vertex 1
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,       // vertex 3
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,       // vertex 2

          // face 3:
          1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,     // vertex 0
          1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,      // vertex 1
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,        // vertex 3
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,       // vertex 2

          // face 4:
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      // vertex 0
          - 1.0f, 1.0f, - 1.0f,       // vertex 1
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,     // vertex 3
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,    // vertex 2

          // face 5:
          1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,      // vertex 0
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, 1.0f,     // vertex 1
          - 1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,     // vertex 3
          1.0f, - 1.0f, - 1.0f,     // vertex 2
          // 6 faces with 4 vertices with 6 components (floats)

      };
      vertexData.put(vertices);

      vertexData.flip();

      FloatBuffer textureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * textureSize);
      textureData.put(new float[] {
          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

          1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
      });
      textureData.flip();

      vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

      vboTextureHandle = glGenBuffers();
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureHandle);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
//      if(! hasBeenRendered) {

         canDraw = true;
         glPushMatrix();
         {
            glTranslatef(loc.getX(), loc.getY(), loc.getZ());
            //glRotatef(x, 1, 1, 0);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

            //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE, type.getTexture().getTextureID());
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, type.getTexture().getTextureID());

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
            glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

            glBindTexture(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureHandle);
            glTexCoordPointer(textureSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, amountOfVertices);
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

         }

         glPopMatrix();
         //hasBeenRendered = true;   }
   }
```

[The output looks something like this](http://gyazo.com/715f6e5659f7c399c7b8a53b27a47fa4.png).

If you need any more information please let me know, I've been struggling with this a lot. I know GL_QUADS is deprecated but I'd really like to get this running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL cube vertices are wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945859/opengl-cube-vertices-are-wrong)

Comment: It isn't. Same code different question. Even so, it's not like anybody is going to dig back to find that question and add their answer.

Comment: Can you post your render result?

Answer (score 0):

Could you also provide which OpenGL you use/target? In GL 1.1 everything is optional ( like VBOs ) but in older ( i.e. more recent ) versions lots of things changed so you can exchange glVertexPointer / glTexCoordPointer with glVertexAttribPointer.
Let's just assume you use the old OpenGL then just remove the VBO and check it out with direct pointers.

Also try to specify the indices yourself even if they are straight forward but it's better to create a list and specify it by hand with glDrawElements.

Java is not really fond of native stuff so you need to use the proper buffer format for OpenGL otherwise it may mess up the data that may look like the results you got.

```
vertexData.put(vertices);
vertexData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexData.flip();
```

Other than these you need to break it down into smaller parts, like just draw a Quad and see the results since it may be a problem with how you lay out your vertex/UV data after all.